# Telerik Radlistview with nested ASP.NET Repeater

Tags: telerik, radlistview

I have a Radlistview that displays items from the database, such as email, password, the domain of the email and so on.  In my ItemInsertTemplate I have it so the user enters a group of emails and the information that pertaines to that email... example the template displays inputs for 5 emails. Now I want the ItemTemplate, so for every time the Radlistview enters the ItemTemplate I want the Radlistview to display the emails that are in the same group by the groupID that is used when the user inserts those emails. I am trying to find a solution for using a nested asp.net repeater within the Radlistview but no luck. Is there a way to pull in rows from the database and group them by the groupID and have the Radlistview display them in a table by group. That way there is a list of grouped emails not just the Radlistview displaying each email in its own Radlistview table. This also has to be updated as groups as well.

```
<ItemTemplate>
            <fieldset style="float:left; height: 145px; width: 250px; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 5px;
                            margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 15px;">

                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >                                                
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">

                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 1%">
                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfItemSeedID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("SeedID") %>' />
                                    </td>                                   
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfDomainID" runat="Server" Value='<%# Eval("DomainID") %>' />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 25%"><b>Seed:</b></td>
                                    <td style="width: 50%">
                                       <%# Eval("seedName")%>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 25%"><b>Email Domain:</b></td>
                                    <td style="width: 50%">
                                       <%# Eval("DomainName")%>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 25%"><b>Password:</b></td>
                                    <td style="width: 50%">
                                        <%# Eval("password")%>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                    <td style="width: 25%"><b>Seed Status:</b></td>
                                    <td style="width: 50%">
                                       <%# Eval("statusName")%>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>                            
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <table style="width: 100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" CausesValidation="false" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

This is what I have so far for my ItemTemplate in my RadListView

Comment: You might try the telerik support forums for this: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I will post this on there as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you heavily count on real grouping capability, you need to replace the listview with the telerik ajax grid. It supports data grouping out-of-the-box with integrated feature.